# Thread порядок выполнения

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Использую  `Thread`. Запускаю его `myThread.start();`. После него у меня идет открытие нового интента. Как сделать так чтоб он вызывался, когда закончится  `Thread`, а не сразу.

```
  final ProgressDialog dialog;
            /**
             * Progress Dialog for User Interaction
             */
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            Thread myThread = new Thread( // создаём новый поток
                                    new Runnable() { // описываем объект Runnable в конструкторе
                                        public void run() {
                                            generateClan_Dannie(hashMap, clan_id);// вызываем метод воспроизведения
                                        }
                                    }
                            );



                            myThread.start();

                            Intent intent;
                            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivityClan.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            getActivity().finish();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 final ProgressDialog dialog;
            /**
             * Progress Dialog for User Interaction
             */
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            Thread myThread = new Thread( // создаём новый поток
                                    new Runnable() { // описываем объект Runnable в конструкторе
                                        public void run() {
                                            generateClan_Dannie(hashMap, clan_id);// вызываем метод воспроизведения
                                        }
                                    }
                            );



                            myThread.start();
                            try {
                               myThread.join(); //та строка, что заставит ждать поток.
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            Intent intent;
                            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivityClan.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            getActivity().finish();/
```

Но вообще, в `android` не рекомендуется вызывать сырые потоки, используйте лучше `AsyncTask` \ `runOnUiThread` или Сервисы

Comment: Спасибо))))))))